# Compilation failed for R package due to 'math.h' file missing

Tags: r, xcode, clang, rcpp, r-package

Recently, I've updated my MacOS to version 10.15.6. Since then, one of my previously installed R packages, 'largeVis', cannot work. I tried to re-install the package but it failed due to file 'math.h' cannot be found.
The command I used to install the package is:

`R CMD INSTALL largeVis_0.2.tar.gz`

The error message is:

```
  file not found
#include_next <math.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘largeVis’
* removing‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/largeVis’
* restoring previous‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/largeVis’
```

However, I do find the 'math.h' file under that folder. I tried several approaches but all failed, for example, reinstall the xcode command line.
Can anyone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: So did you run `xcode-select --install` or `xcodebuild -license accept`?

Comment: Or possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461195/error-install-rcpparmadillo-on-macos-catalina

Comment: Yes, I tried both but not working

Comment: I would recommend to open an issue on the GitHub repo of the package. Which you already did? (https://github.com/elbamos/largeVis/issues/60).
Try not to duplicate your questions.