# Install with devtools::install_github() fails to detect build tools

Tags: r, github, devtools

This is my first time trying to download a Github package, and I'm running into some trouble using RStudio v1.2.5033 on MacOS Big Sur v11.2.1.

Initially, when running

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('xuyiqing/gsynth')
```

I was getting this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gsynth’ had non-zero exit status
```

Did some reading, and it looked like I needed to download Command Line Tools, so I downloaded XCode CLI, clang4, and gfortran. Now I am getting a pop-up message saying:

"Install Build Tools
Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools.
Do you want to install the additional tools now?
Y/N"

If I click "No", I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to install 'gsynth' from GitHub:
  Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.
```

Running the above pkgbuild code in an R console, this is what I get:

```
Trying to compile a simple C file
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.
rror: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking "yes"?

Comment: If I click yes it just brings me to this webpage: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-in-os-x/, which just tells me to download the tools I've already downloaded.

Comment: Also having this issue with mac M1 running Big Sur

Comment: I'm not sure if you have experience using vim, but I found this solution that looks like it worked for someone else. I'm just really not a programmer, and can't quite figure out what they did. If you're able to figure it out and can explain to me in a more step-by-step way, that would be amazing! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865695/rcpp-fails-to-compile-c-code-after-series-of-updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are a few issues that you need to overcome to install this package (xcode command line tools and OpenMP support for a start), but you should overcome them if you follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340

After making the necessary changes, I successfully installed gsynth on my system (macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 / R version 4.0.3) using `devtools::install_github('xuyiqing/gsynth')` without issue.

--

Here are the instructions in case the link above dies:

1. Reinstall xcode command line tools (even if it says "up to date")

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Install gcc & llvm via Homebrew ([instructions for installing Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)) or, if you already have gcc/llvm installed via Homebrew, skip to the next step

```
# This can take several hours
brew install gcc
brew install llvm
```

3. Once you have gcc & llvm installed via Homebrew:

```
brew cleanup
brew update
brew upgrade
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall llvm
```

4. Link some headers into /usr/local/include

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/

# You can safely ignore warnings like this:
#ln: /usr/local/include//tcl.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclPlatDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMath.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMathDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tk.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkPlatDecls.h: File exists
```

5. Create a new `~/.R/Makevars` file (if you already have a `~/.R/Makevars` file, save it in a different directory (away from `~/.R/`)) and include only these lines in the file:

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++

LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
CC=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

6. Compile a package from source in R/Rstudio

```
# To check whether openmp is enabled, compile data.table:
install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
```

7. If your package fails to compile, a couple of SO users have had to install a fresh gfortran (re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340), which you can download from https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/10.2-bigsur-intel

### Update (2022/04/05)

I had an error when updating "RcppAlgos" (couldn't find gmp.h or libgmp). I checked gmp was installed (`brew install gmp`), then added /usr/local/include to CPPFLAGS and /usr/local/lib to LDFLAGS in the ~/.R/Makevars file to solve the problem, i.e.

```
cat ~/.R/Makevars
LOC=/usr/local/gfortran
CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp

CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib,-L/usr/local/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include

FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
```

Comment: This worked - thanks! It did fail to compile on step 6, but seems to be working now after installing a fresh gfortran.

Comment: I have spent half a day trying to fix this problem. Everything worked as suggested till step 5. Step 6 failed and I downloaded and installed gfortran from the link above. I tried step 6 after installing gfortran and it again failed. Basically I am back to square one where I can't install gsynth from Github. Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using an Intel mac or an M1 silicon mac? If you change  `CC=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc -fopenmp` to `CC=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc` and `CXX=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++ -fopenmp` to `CXX=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++` are you able to compile the data.table package from source?