# Macos Monterey on M1: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace while compiling under g++

Tags: c++, xcode, apple-m1, toolchain, macos-monterey

While compiling with g++/c++/clang/clang++ I always get:

```
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/numeric:151:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:323:9: error: no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:324:9: error: no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:325:9: error: no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:326:9: error: no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:327:7: error: no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater'?
using ::isgreater;
      ^~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:742:29: note: '::std::greater' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from A.cpp:8:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/numeric:151:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:328:7: error: no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater_equal'?
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ^~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:771:29: note: '::std::greater_equal' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater_equal : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from A.cpp:8:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/numeric:151:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:329:9: error: no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:330:9: error: no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:331:9: error: no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:332:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:333:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
```

I have already tried to reinstall gcc, Xcode and Xcode Command Line Tools. I've looked at [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th), but the answer there is based around the fact that I failed to setup Cmake when I'm using pure g++. Also, that answer redirected me to [Cannot compile R packages with c++ code after updating to macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313047/cannot-compile-r-packages-with-c-code-after-updating-to-macos-catalina), where best answer suggests to run `xcode-select --install`, which I've already tried.

I've also tried to `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, but it didn't help either.

Comment: It's usually better to avoid the unnecessary noise by not adding unrelated info (like the exact model of a machine) to a coding question that has little to do with hardware. Some info about the processor's family can be beneficial though.